# Show that the path of shortest hyperbolic length satisfies $(x-c)^2+y^2=r^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

The hyperbolic length of a curve $y:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{RxR}_+$ is given by the functional $$\lambda(y)=\int_a^b\frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{y}dx$$  Show that the path of shortest hyperbolic length satisfies $(x-c)^2+y^2=r^2$ for $c,r\in\mathbb{R}$.  We are approaching this problem using calculus of variations and I've used the Euler-Lagrange differential equation to show: $$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{y'}{y\sqrt{1+y'^2}})=\frac{-\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{y^2}$$ and $$\frac{1}{y\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=C$$ where C is a constant, but now I've been stuck for a while.  Does anyone have advice or a hint they could give me?

Comment: How did you get the second equation in regards to that quantity being a constant?

Comment: Since the Lagrange function inside the integral does not depend explicitly on x, then $L_{y'}(x,y,y')-L(x,y,y')=C$.  From there I just simplified to get that expression.

Comment: Ah. Conservation of energy

Comment: Can you please explain how that is $L_{y'} - L$?  I get something different.  I am tired though..

Comment: Oh, you mean $L_{y'} y' - L$, then yes. I see

Comment: Anyway I'm getting tired, my only suggestion is to write it out as $$ \frac{d}{dx} Cy' = -\frac{1}{Cy^3}$$ but you probably already have done this.  If not, try to see if you can show this gets a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $c=1/C^2$ your ODE is $y^2(1+y'^2)=c$, which solved for $yy'$ is
$$yy'=\sqrt{c-y^2}.$$
Now put $u=y^2$ so that $u'=2yy',$ and get to
$$\frac{u'}{\sqrt{c-u}}=2.$$
With $v=c-u$ and $dv=-du$ integrating the sides gives
$$v^{1/2}=-x+k/2,$$
so $v=(x-k/2)^2$, then $c-u=c-y^2=(x-k/2)^2$, i.e. 
$$(x-k/2)^2+y^2=c.$$